# Select Digital Assets from Media Manager in custom page and Save in CMS as component

Tags: ecl, media-manager

I'm creating a custom page(Asp.net MVC solution) using core services to create a component. And that component has Image and Video field. I need to get digital assets from Media Manager and then create component. I'm able to access media manager assets but only getting "Direct Link" from it. But to store component in CMS, i will need ECL link of those assets.  so can anyone help me in how can i get ECL link for selected media manager item so it can be stored in multimedia field in component?

Comment: Are you using the ECL-based Media Manager connector from SDL? Doesn't sound like you are

Comment: We are using out of box media manager connector from SDL. do we have separate version "ECL-based media manager connector" to ECL Links? Apologies as not aware of media manager connectors so needs bit of clarity. Thanks for help

Comment: It is the same... this should store the MM items as ECL components in the CM

Comment: Thanks for clarity. i'm able to use MM items as ECL component in CMS. But is it possible to get ECL link of MM item if i try to select MM item on custom page created in external application thru core services?

Answer (score 2):

To play with ECL directly. You need to use `Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2`
Get the below mentioned required Dlls from your Tridion InstallatioN

- Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.dll
- Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.dll
- Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.dll

[Documentation of ECL API](https://sdl.dist.sdlmedia.com/Distributions/?o=B5AD0AAD-A276-4734-9D6D-A000EC8F1EB1)

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to use .and select media manager items through CMS directly. But my question is different. i want to select multimedia item on custom page(using asp.net MVC application) created using core services. so its ans external application where i want to select multimedia item and while selecting i need ECL link

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Your question/need require more clarity. ECL is used to expose external media to CMS. how come core service is used to create media in external application?  what you want to achieve? why you need ECL link?